# Discount on an item

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> An item in a shop is offered at a discount of $10\%.$ It is sold during clearance sale at $6\%$ discount over the already discounted price at $846\$.$ What's the original marked price of the item?

My attempt: Let the original price be $x.$ So, $0.9*0.94*x=846 \implies x=1000.$

But the answer is $900.$ I wish somebody could help. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the answer is flawed, because what you've done is correct. $900$ would include the $10\%$ markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation correctly gives the undiscounted price of the item. I suspect that the difficulty lies in the correct interpretation of *original marked price*. You’ve taken that to be the undiscounted price. However, the statement of the problem probably means that the item is normally offered at a $10$% discount; if that’s the case, then the normal marked price in that shop includes the $10$% discount and is therefore $\$900$.

Comment: I suspect "original marked price" is undiscounted as the OP calculated. But all this weasely language contributes to my hatred of clothes shopping.

Comment: @dfeuer: I dislike shopping for anything — except books.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is fine; the answer must be incorrect.

It looks like what the answer you have been given refers to the price after the first discount.

The fully-discounted price is 846. So before the 6% mark down the price would have been:

$(846 \div 94) \times 100 = 900$

Which means that the original price (before any mark downs at all) is:

$(900 \div 90) \times 100 = 1000$

Solution; it's a poorly worded problem!